# Creating a hyperlink that references itself and continues to do so when filled down

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, hyperlink

I have code that copies the row of the active cell and replicates it in a new row under the selected cell and a hyperlink that calls the code.

In the example below, if I click on the top ‘clickMe’:

'clickMe', date1, formula1, formula2

'clickMe', date2, formula1, formula2

The row is replicated under the row where I clicked the hyperlink:

'clickMe', 'date1', formula1, formula2

'clickMe', 'date1', formula1, formula2

'clickMe', 'date2', formula1, formula2

The problem I have is that the only way I know how to configure the hyperlink to call the code is to reference itself, but I must type in the cell reference. I need to replicate this on many rows so I would like to fill the hyperlink down to the other cells. This does not work, because the original hyperlink's cell reference is persisted and so it is always the top row that is duplicated and not the row in which I clicked.

Does anyone know how to configure a hyperlink to reference itself, so that when filled down it continues to reference itself and not the original cell it was dragged from?

Comment: ... and what exactly is your question? If it is "please write this code for me for free", you won't get that here. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: Please edit your question and add the clarification there. Don't add details in comments. Post a comment when your question has been fixed.